# component service not being injected into test in jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

Given the following test.
The `$provided` service is not being injected. If I debug the test in karma I can see that the service being provided is the **real one**, and **not the mock**.

The really weird thing, is that if I remove the `$provide.service...` I get an error Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ficaServiceProvider <- ficaService. This clearly means that the service is getting registered, just not replaced?

```
describe("component: FicaStatusComponent",
    function () {
        var fs;
        beforeEach(function () {
            module("aureus",
                function ($provide) {
                    $provide.service("ficaService", function () {
                        this.status = function () {
                            return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
                                resolve([{ documentType: { id: 1 } }]);
                            });
                        }
                    })
                });

        });

        beforeEach(inject(function (_$componentController_, _ficaService_) {
            $componentController = _$componentController_;
            fs = _ficaService_;
        }));

        it("should expose a `fica` object", function () {
            console.log('should expose');
            var bindings = {};
            var ctrl = $componentController("ficaStatus", null, bindings);
            expect(ctrl.fica).toBeDefined();
        });

        it("compliant with no documents should not be compliant",
            function () {
                var ctrl = $componentController("ficaStatus");
                expect(ctrl.fica.length).toEqual(1);
            });
    }
);
```

The second test **compliant with no documents...** is failing.

> Chrome 56.0.2924 (Windows 10 0.0.0) component: FicaStatusComponent compliant with no documents should not be compliant FAILED
>           Error: Unexpected request: GET api/fica/status/

I have also tried this, expecting to have an empty object injected, but the "real" service is there nevertheless?

```
        module("aureus", function($provide) {
            $provide.value("ficaService", function() { return {}; });
            $provide.service("ficaService", function() { return {}; });
        });
```

Here is the implementation of the controller for the component:

```
var FicaStatusController = (function () {
    function FicaStatusController($log, $loc, ficaService) {
        var _this = this;
        this.$log = $log;
        this.$loc = $loc;
        this.ficaService = ficaService;
        this.fica = [];
        this.ficaService.status(1234).then(function (_) { return _this.fica = _; });
    }

FicaStatusController.$inject = ["$log", "$location", "IFicaStatusService"];
module("aureus").component("ficaStatus", new FicaStatusComponent());
module("aureus").service("IFicaStatusService", FicaStatusService);
```

The service is as follows:

```
var FicaStatusService = (function () {
    function FicaStatusService($log, $http) {
        this.$log = $log;
        this.$http = $http;
    }
    FicaStatusService.prototype.status = function (accountNumber) {
        var url = "api/fica/status/" + accountNumber;
        this.$log.log("status: " + url);
        return this.$http
            .get(url)
            .then(function (_) { return _.data; });
    };
    return FicaStatusService;
}());

...
```

Comment: I haven't worked much with $componentController but from reading the angular docs it looks like you aren't injecting the service properly. Does `$componentController("ficaStatus", {ficaService: fs }, bindings);` do the trick?

Comment: darn, I really thought you were on to something there. nope... no cigar, thanks for trying!

Comment: if you can supply me a full working example I can probably figure it out. I tried working with what you already posted and I can't get it working. There is nothing on my `ctrl` object to work with.

Comment: I see what the problem is with the mock service but I can't seem to get `ctrl` to have any properties unless I supply them in the `bindings` variable. Is that how it's supposed to work? I haven't done any work with the component directive before so I'm shooting in the dark over here. :-(

Comment: I might be missing something here, you have declared `IFicaStatusService` as the real one but trying to mock the `ficaService`.

Comment: the naming of these dependencies is confusing... I needed to use the `IFicaStatusService` name, not the property name. I was mistakenly assuming that the javascript property key needed to be used. eminlala, do you want to post that as the answer and claim the bounty...

Comment: @Jim can you create a fiddle/plunker out of it? guessing answers won't work with this amount of code

Comment: @eminlala got the answer correct, I need to inject `_IFicaStatusService_` not `ficaService` I didn't understand the mechanism by which the dependency is injected into the test. I am waiting for @eminlala to claim the bounty by posting the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added your service in your module like this:

`module("aureus").service("IFicaStatusService", FicaStatusService);`

That means that you will need to provide `IFicaStatusService` instead of `ficaService` with `$provide`.